# Webview shouldInterceptRequest method always return null

Tags: webview, kotlin

Webview shouldInterceptRequest method always return null.I gone use method for adblocking.I tried lots of adblock method but always need this shouldInterceptRequest method but its return null.

My webview code

```
webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {

        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?): Boolean {




            view!!.loadUrl(request!!.url.toString())
            return true


        }

        override fun shouldInterceptRequest(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?): WebResourceResponse {
            return if (

                    AdBlocker.isAd(request!!.url.toString()))
                AdBlocker.createEmptyResource()
            else
                super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request)
        }



        override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
            eTadres.setText(url)


            suankiurl= url!!
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
        }



        override fun onLoadResource(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
            if (webView.visibility==View.GONE){webView.visibility=View.VISIBLE}
            super.onLoadResource(view, url)
        }


    }
```

Error Log

```
W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException: super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request) must not be null
10-19 17:46:53.185 306-349/com.bulamac.tarayicibulamac W/System.err:     at com.bulamac.tarayicibulamac.WebviewFragment$onCreateView$5.shouldInterceptRequest(WebviewFragment.kt:182)
10-19 17:46:53.185 306-349/com.bulamac.tarayicibulamac W/System.err:     at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter.shouldInterceptRequest(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:52)
10-19 17:46:53.185 306-349/com.bulamac.tarayicibulamac W/System.err:     at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents$BackgroundThreadClientImpl.shouldInterceptRequest(AwContents.java:9)
10-19 17:46:53.185 306-349/com.bulamac.tarayicibulamac W/System.err:     at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsBackgroundThreadClient.shouldInterceptRequestFromNative(AwContentsBackgroundThreadClient.java:11)
10-19 17:46:53.186 306-349/com.bulamac.tarayicibulamac A/chromium: [FATAL:jni_android.cc(243)] Please include Java exception stack in crash report
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request)` will always return null (look implementation for this code). If you want to prevent app from crashing you should use example below

Change to this ': WebResourceResponse?' ('?' was added)

```
override fun shouldInterceptRequest(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?): WebResourceResponse? {
            return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request)` It is expected to return null, check the return type of your `override fun shouldInterceptRequest`, it should be nullable according to the documentation:

> A WebResourceResponse containing the response information or null if the WebView should load the resource itself.